# How to add commentary types or category for a post

Tags: categories, comments

I need to create three types of comments por a post. The idea is to not mix up all the comments and let the users comments for a particular subject of the post. So define comments type A, type B and type C for a post. The users read the post and comment on the subject define on type A or the others. Any idea would be truly helpful, thanks!

Comment: I don't entirely follow exactly what you are trying to do. It sounds interesting and possibly unique. Maybe if you summarised what you have tried so far, someone might be able to offer appropriate advice.

Comment: An Example. A post for a game. People just comment the game. I wanna to have 3 types of comments. Comments form team A - comments for Team B and comments for the referee.  This way all the comments are not mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

> An Example. A post for a game. People just comment the game. I wanna
> to have 3 types of comments. Comments form team A - comments for Team
> B and comments for the referee. This way all the comments are not
> mixed up.

## The hard way

If I were to undertake such a project, my first instinct would be to define three custom post types. Team A, Team B, and Referee. I would give them only headline and comment. I would also define a post_meta such as "_root_post".

Then I would hook the new post action and generate one of each for the new post, adding the post_meta key we invented with the post's ID as the value.

This would give us three threads that can be used. To access them, I would create a child theme and modify the way it handles comments. Instead of the comments for the post itself, I would do a custom query for meta value `_root_post == $post_id`. Then just lay out three types of comment.

After planning all that, I would think, "man, that is a lot of work. Is there an easier way?" Because, quite frankly, this is a terrible idea.

## Somewhat easier way

I would google "[comment meta](https://www.google.com/search?q=comment%20meta&oq=comment%20meta)" to find out if that was a thing, discover it is, and think about using [add_comment_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_comment_meta/) and [get_comment_meta](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comment_meta/).

A further google tells me that the hook [comment_form](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_form/) would allow me to add extra form elements to comments. The hook [comment_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/comment_post/) would allow me to grab my form data and apply a meta value to the comment (A, B, or C).

Now all I have to do is a child theme edit to layout three comment types so they are nice and readable. I could then custom query the comments grouped by my meta value. For layout, I'd probably use JavaScript-powered tabs or something.

## Conclusions

I would choose the second and less complex approach unless there is a bringing need to use the first and more complete method. A few custom hooks in your child-themes `functions.php` and a custom comment template and you are all ready to go.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll try to do this way